# What kind of MOSFET use as a switch touch on, touch- off

Tags: mosfet, switches

What kind of MOSFET (or other component you suggest) will be the adequate to use as a switch (touch on, touch-off) with the following information:

- Power In = 2.7 to 6.2 V when on.
- Power out = close to zero when off.
- Switch on = with momentary contact button with less than 6V and stay on until the contact of the same  momentary button to turn off (and stay off until the next momentary contact turn it on)
- Power = two coin cell batteries component (CR2032 times 2) total 6V
- Vibrator pancake motor Intensity = 100mA + LED = 30mA

If you could please advise me, it would be very nice. Thanks
Juan Marin

Comment: Power ≠ voltage. You shouldn't confuse the two.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very low voltage on-off latch circuit: -

[image]

Inverter U1 and U2 are wired in a circle and that forms the basic latch. When the on/off button is pressed, the voltage accumulated on C1 will be the inverse of the voltage on the input of U1 therefore the switch reverses the input by overriding the positive feedback from U2's output.

If I were building this circuit I'd probably replace Q1 with a FET for operating on supplies from 2.7V to 6V because the FET would likely turn on more powerfully and it can take a gate drive across the range of power voltages you need. The BJT is OK but may get a little warm Running below 2V will probably need a BJT because it will switch on at lower supply voltages better than a FET.

If you use a FET, look for one that has a low Vgs(threshold) voltage to ensure it works down at 2.7V. Also check the inverters (U1 and U2) to make sure they can run from 6V. If (say) 5.5V is the max limit for these parts you might want to power the inverters using a LDO low power regulator or resistor and zener diode.

Should you need a switching element in the positive rail to the motor then a suitable P channel FET should be looked for, again with low Vgs(threshold).

[This](http://www.discovercircuits.com/DJ-Circuits/Low-Voltage-Latching.htm) is the link to the author's page.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the "which MOSFET" part of the question:

For a touch-on/touch-off switch i.e. toggle mode latching touch switch, an IC such as the Atmel [AT42QT1012](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-9543-AT42-QTouch-BSW-AT42QT1012_Datasheet.pdf) can provide touch-based on-off control with minimal additional components:

[image: Schematic]

The sense electrode can be any conductive area, such as a pad etched on the PCB layout itself. This device auto-calibrates to the parameters of the implementation, and re-calibrates itself periodically. Hence sensing remains robust even as environmental conditions (e.g. humidity) change, or as grime builds up over the touch area.

As an added bonus, this part can **sense proximity**, even without physical contact, so it can be used within sealed devices if desired. Not sure of the following is documented, but with a bit of experimentation, the **IC itself can be used as the touch sensor**, dispensing with the need for a sense pad.

Other similar single-IC solutions include the [Hobbytronics TIC1 touch switch IC](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/touch-switch-ic), with two sense channels - However, having found no datasheet for this device, I wouldn't recommend it.